# Rewrite GET Query String using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to `Rewrite` my `GET Query String` from this -

```
http://www.example.com/verify.php?key=547b52f2b5d20d258e62de1e27b55c
```

to this

```
http://www.example.com/verify/547b52f2b5d20d258e62de1e27b55c
```

I am using the following rule but it does not seem to work -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php

RewriteRule    ^[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    verify.php?key=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: `verify?=keybf3` is the URL actually like that?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Edited my question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /verify\.php\?key=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^verify\.php$ /verify/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^verify/([^/]+)/?$ /verify.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
```